# css background image (and animation)

Tags: css

I'm going crazy because of the 2 images on the sides..in my screen (17" fhd) with Firefox everything looks perfect (with IE instead is wrong) but I tried on an older (not fhd) 17" screen and they look crappy..I connected another 17" pc to a 42" tv and it's slightly better but still not acceptable..what should I do to have them nice and fixed in every screen? media queries?

[here](http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/9eLinoMk/file.html) how I want it (and how I see it on my pc with Firefox)

[here](http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/8HQ1kFQZ/file.html) how I see it with other pc (and in my pc but with IE)

at [this](http://www.assatena.it/Atena/test_css_anim) link you can try it on your browser

the faulty ones show the left larger and cut on the right edge. the right is much smaller and shorter (does not cover from top to bottom screen)

and this is the code I have right now

```
#contenitore {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  background-image: url(img/cl_at_small.jpg);
  background-size: contain;/*2000px 950px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;*/
  z-index: -9999;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s infinite;
  animation: animatedBackground 40s infinite;   
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#imL{
  background-image: url(img/AT_X.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#imR{
  position: fixed;
  right: -1px;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(img/anno2015.jpg);
  background-size:contain;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  100% {
    background-position: -1400px 0px; } 
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  100% {
    background-position: -1400px 0px; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  100% {
    background-position: -1400px 0px; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  100% {
    background-position: -1400px 0px; } 
}
```

thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you used "background-size: cover;" for the left image, but "background-size: contain;" for the right-hand image?

Answer (score 0):

What if you specify a min-height or change the current height classification to px height instead of a % height.

Answer (score 0):

You used `"background-size: contain;"` change this to `"background-size: cover;"` for `#imR`

Try this

```
#imR {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0;
      background-image: url(img/anno2015.jpg);
      background-size: cover; //changed this
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 10%;
      z-index: 9999;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just have a mixup in your css: in the image that behaves the way you want, you have

```
background-size: cover;
```

in the right image, you have:

```
background-size: contain;
```

Switching the right image to "cover" makes them at least behave the same.